# Stylish: How to backup styles in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, backup, google-chrome-extensions, stylish

[Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) is the **Chrome** (and Firefox) extension.

I would like to **export** all the styles I have installed (and modified some) and **import** them into Stylish in Chrome on another computer.

Is there a way how I could do this?

Where exactly does Stylish save the installed styles in Chrome? Could I just copy that folder/those files?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great News, finally Stylish 1.7.2 has export/import function

Comment: Oh look, indeed it does. Amazing

Comment: What is the file format?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can find them in " %appdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe_0 "

I found the answer here: https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/31168/where-are-user-styles-stored-on-chrome

Answer (score 2):

I don't use any 'windows', but in Linux (KDE or Enlightenment desktops) look in the following location. the 'xxxx' will be a bunch of characters.
Stylish is stored in an .sqlite 'database'. I'm using DB Browser for SQLite right now. It seems pretty good under Qt, but miss SQLiteManager.

```
~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/databases/chrome-extension_XXXXXXXX
```

in my case, the db is named merely '2' as it must have been the second extension needing a sqlite db I installed.

I copied '2.sqlite' to anther instance of Google-Chrome (Chromium actually). 
You NEED to install Stylish for Chrome FIRST.
Backup ('compress here', rename or tar) the installed, default db
Copy the db ('2') to the Stylish extension directory, renaming it to the bd created when the stylish ext was added.

Start Chrome / Chromium and click on 'Stylish button' and choose 'manage installed styles'.
You should see all your styles you built on your 'other' instance of chrome.

Hope this helps someone.
Landis.

ps, i don't have an easy way of telling which extension directory is for Stylish. You need to open each db and see if the 'style' Table exists.
If it does, look in Table section_meta. You should see the effected urls for the styles you've created.

Comment: Nice!! I'll try this out :)

The bunch of characters should be `fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe`, that's Stylish's ID I guess (its URL in the webstore is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)

so in my case it's `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe_0`

Answer (score 1):

Since Google profile keeps information like all of your extensions, you might try to log in with your account on the other PC. Did you try it?

Comment: I have logged in, yes. That resulted in all of my extensions getting downloaded automatically, including Stylish, but unfortunately without its data (the styles).

(I have done that a few times before as well, the styles have never got synced along with the extension)